# Is the Reporting Services Integration for SharePoint 2007 Really Worth the Effort?

Tags: reporting-services, 2007

I have had nothing but frustration with MOSS 2007 SP2 + SharePoint Reporting Services + SQL 2005 SP2. I even followed Raju Sakthivel's guide to SSRS + SharePoint Integration , but I cannot publish a model when using VS2005.

VS2005 fails to publish after this SOAP call

```
<ListSecureMethods xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/06/30/reporting/reportingservices" />
```

With the following SOAP exception

```
<faultstring>The operation  is not supported on a report server that is configured to run in SharePoint integrated mode. ---&gt; The operation  is not supported on a report server that is configured to run in SharePoint integrated mode.</faultstring>
```

Now according to [Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155398.aspx), this is by default which puzzles me

> When a report server is configured for
>   SharePoint integrated mode, the
>   ReportService2005 APIs will return an
>   **rsOperationNotSupportedSharePointMode** 
>   error. If the report server is
>   configured for native mode, the
>   ReportService2006  APIs will return an
>   **rsOperationNotSupportedNativeMode**
>   error.

So,

- how do you publish reports to a report server that is integrated with SharePoint?
- Is it worth integrating it?
- Do you have any success stories?

ps: there is nothing in the supported/unsupported features of this integration that should prevent me from publishing reports. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326290.aspx

Comment: The way this question is phrased makes it very subjective which isn't really supported by the community guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

I think reporting services is really worth the effort. We use RS in many of our customers implementations. 
Can you elaborate on your problems (and update your question)?

Answer (score 1):

Don't run in integration mode. Just have a separate report server, published through ISA/TMG means you wont get auth. issues. 
You can then make some pretty pages within sharepoint that then link to your reports.
@crmckinley

Comment: Thanks Chris, I am thinking about it.  Nice blog btw..sharepointedutech.com

Answer (score 0):

I agree with WICTOR its worth the effort.
So,

•how do you publish reports to a report server that is integrated with SharePoint?
If you are using MOSS just create a document lib with a content type of Report Center Content type.
If you are on WSS create a Document Lib and then deploy your RS reports to mthe lib.
One for Datasource the other for Reports...easy

•Is it worth integrating it?
Yes if you can its much more flexible and well integrated with Sharepoint and more permissions to play with
•Do you have any success stories?
Yes.
Hope that helps